# Rails: How to trigger the after_destroy callback when deleting nested join model records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nested-attributes

I've 3 models `User`, `Feature`, `UserFeature`

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_features
  has_many :features, through: :user_features
end


class Feature < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_features
  has_many :users, through: :user_features
end


class UserFeature < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :feature
end
```

I've already created many features in DB, and associated features with user while creating user with following code

```
<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
  // some user_fields
  <% Feature.all.each do |feature| %>
     <%= check_box "user[feature_ids][], feature.id %>
  <% end %>
  // submit button here
<% end %>
```

In my `UserController` I've this code

```
class UserController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @user = User.new(permit_params)
    @user.save
  end

  def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @user.update_attributes(permit_params)
  end 

  private
    def permit_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, user_feature_ids: [])
    end
end
```

When I submit it will create and update the user and make entries in `UserFeature` Table for those features that I've checked.

When update user if I unchecked any feature then it will delete relative record from `UserFeature`

Here don't have any issue everything works as expected.

But now I want to perform some activity when a user_feature is delete.

For this I wrote a callback in UserFeature `after_destroy :some_activity`

```
class UserFeature < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :feature

  after_destroy :some_activity

  def some_activity
     // some code
  end
end
```

but its not working, when I checked why its not calling destroy call while deleting user_feature, I found that it will call a SQL query instead of calling `destroy` on unchecked user_feature.

That's why `after` or `before` `destroy` callback not working.

Could any one let me know, how can I perform any activity while deleting `UserFeature`?

Comment: Did you ever find a work around for this?

Comment: @Babbz77 - I just posted the solution.

Answer (score 0):

The `after_destroy` callback is not fired after `delete`, because this is how `delete` is implemented. Quote from the [docs](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.1/ActiveRecord/Relation/delete):

> Active Record objects are not instantiated, so the object’s callbacks are not executed, including any :dependent association options. [...] Note: Although it is often much faster than the alternative, #destroy, skipping callbacks might bypass business logic in your application that ensures referential integrity or performs other essential jobs.

Instead of an `after_destroy` callback on the association class you can use an `after_remove` callback on the association definition, like described in the [Rails Guide about Association Callbacks](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#association-callbacks).

Comment: yes, I understand delete will not run any callback, that's why I'm asking this question. what is the solution of my problem "I need to perform some activity when delete `UserFeature` "?

Comment: I've try this solution but it only work with after_add and before_add, still not work with after_remove and before_remove

Comment: Yes, the `after_destroy` callback is not fired after `delete`, because this is how `delete` is implemented. But why is `delete` called in the first place? Because in the above example, the deletion is implemented as an "Automatic deletion of a join model" (see: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association). And no, the Association Callback `after_remove` does not work in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to **not** set up your code to use the "[Automatic deletion of a join model](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association)" mode (because this mode **won't** trigger the callback for the deletion).

Instead, set up your code as a standard nested resource using the `accepts_nested_attributes_for` declaration, which **will** trigger the callback for the deletion.

The models would be:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_features
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :user_features, allow_destroy: true
end

class Feature < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_features
end

class UserFeature < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :feature

  after_destroy :some_activity

  def some_activity
    # Some code here to be executed after the Object destruction
  end
end
```

Note:

- You **don't** need the `through:` in the `has_many` declaration, because you won't be using the getter/setter `.feature_ids` that would come with it.
- You **do** need the `accepts_nested_attributes_for` declaration with the `allow_destroy: true` option.

The form would be:

```
<%= form_for @user do |user_form| %>

  // Any User fields here

  <%= user_form.fields_for :user_features, @user_features do |user_feature_form| %>

    // The UserFeature check_box field:
    <%= user_feature_form.check_box :_destroy,
                                    { checked: user_feature_form.object.persisted?,
                                      class: 'my_class' },
                                       checked_value = false,
                                     unchecked_value = true %>

    // Any other UserFeature fields here, i.e.:
    <%= user_feature_form.number_field :quantity,
                                        class: 'my_class' %>

  <% end %>

  // Submit button here

<% end %>
```

Note:

- Use the `.fields_for` method for the generation of the `UserFeature` fields.
- The check_box must have the method `:_destroy`.
- `checked_value` must be `false` (if checked, then **don't** delete)
- `unchecked_value` must be `true` (if unchecked, then **do** delete)

The (basic) Controller would be:

```
class UserController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @user = User.new(permit_params)
    @user.save
  end

  def new # or: def edit
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    Feature.all.each do |feature|
      user_feature = @user.user_features.select {|u_f| u_f.feature_id == feature.id}[0]

      # If no corresponding UserFeature exists, build it (= non-persisted, which will determine if the check_box is checked or not)
      if user_feature.nil?
        @user.user_features.build(feature_id: feature.id, quantity: nil)
      end
    end

    # Optional: Sort (i.e. by Feature.name) to keep the list order fixed (pass this array to the form)
    @user_features = @user.user_features.sort_by {|u_f| u_f.feature.name}
  end

  def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @user.update_attributes(permit_params)
  end 

  private
    def permit_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, user_features_attributes: [
                                    :id, :quantity, :_destroy
                                  ])
    end
end
```